# Complex find command with multiple prunings

Tags: shell-script, find, regular-expression

I need to walk a directory tree with multiple starting points e.g. `find ./User1 ./User2 ./User3` but only process specific directory names that exist in any of those starting points, like this: `./User1/Documents` `./User1/Pictures` `/.User2/Documents` etc. I would like to skip *and* `prune` any other subfolders not in a given list from all of the starting points.

All of my attempts at multiple combinations of `-not` and `prune` with `\(` & `\)` have failed.

The starting points will be determined in a script at runtime. As a last resort, I could build up a list of starting points by looping over the list of `User?` and generating an even bigger list of starting points with the desired directory names already appended.

Only `./User?/NotInList` should be excluded but `./User?/InList/NotInList` is OK.

[The big picture: I'm doing data recovery and want to enumerate 'important' files in the Microsoft Windows `Users` folder. I need to skip the `Public` and `Default` folders (so I build up a string of the remaining folders as starting points for the `find` command), and also only select/descend into the `Pictures` `Documents` etc. folders of each user, but not the `AppData` or `Contacts` etc. folders that are rarely important.]

Comment: Why not just `find {User1,User2,...}/{Documents,Pictures,...}`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `User1,User2` will be generated at runtime and I believe variable expansion doesn't work inside braces. Also, what if the names have spaces in them (I could use `\ ` in the braces, but the dynamic usernames will still make trouble.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
users=(User1 User2)
# or users=($(<userlist.txt))
# if userlist.txt contains a list of users as separate words

dirs=(Documents Pictures ...)

find ./$^users/$^dirs
```

Same with `fish`:

```
set users User1 User2 ...
set dirs Documents Pictures
find ./$users/$dirs
```

In `fish` or `zsh -o rcexpandparam`, arrays expand in a brace-expansion fashion. In `zsh`, the `$^array` syntax turns on `rcexpandparam` for that single array expansion.

The reference to `rc` is a bit misleading here. While `$array^string` in `rc`/`es` (where `array` is (1 2)) would expand like `{1,2}string` (and that's the reason why `zsh` chose `^` for its rc-like type of expansion in `$^array`), that doesn't apply for joining arrays together. In `rc`, `$array1^$arrat2` (same as `$array1$array2`) only works for arrays of the same size and joins the element one by one (`(1 2)^(a b)` becomes `1a 2b`, not `1a 1b 2a 2b`).

Note that those are not *globbing*, `User1/Documents` will be passed to `find` regardless of whether that file exists or not. To pass the list of those files or directories that actually *exist*, in `zsh`, you could do

```
find ./$^users/$^dirs(N)
```

which passes adds the `(N)` glob qualifier to all the element resulting of that array multiplication, which has two effects:

- makes them globs which means they will expand to matching files
- if the glob doesn't match any file (they can only match either 0 or 1 as there's no wildcard in  there), the resulting glob expands to nothing instead.

Alternatively, you could go *glob* all the way:

```
find (User1|User2)/(Documents|Pictures)
```

Or based on your example:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
find ./^(#i)(Default|Public)/(Documents|Pictures)
```

Or generate that glob based on the arrays with

```
find (${(j:|:)~${(b)users}})/${(j:|:)~${(b)dirs}}
```

Where:

- `(b)` quotes the wildcard operators if any in the elements of the array
- `(j:|:)` joins them with `|`
- `~` turns on globbing upon the expansion

Those work with arbitrary file names (except those starting with `-` as a limitation of `find`).

To do it with `find` alone would be very tricky, especially if you want to allow arbitrary file names. But for your relatively tamed ones like those `Default`, `Public`...), you could try:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name . -o -path './*/*' \( ! -path './*/*/*' \
  ! -name Documents ! -name Pictures -prune -o -print \) -o   \
  ! -name Default ! -name Public -o -prune
```

(This kind of thing gives me headaches).

That's using standard `find` syntax, if you want a case insensitive match, you can use `-name '[pP][uU][bB][lL][iI][cC]'`, or if using GNU `find` (which you seem to) or compatible, use `-iname Public`.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the answer you posted yourself, you want to pick the directories `./x/y`, where `x` is any of the directories in the current directory, except `Public` or `Default`, and `y` is any of `Documents`, `Pictures`, or `My Documents`.

In Bash, you can do that with a glob when `extglob` is enabled. 
(In ksh, it's the default when the pattern is directly on the command line; in Zsh, you need to use `setopt kshglob`.)

Given:

```
$ mkdir -p {Someuser,"other user",Public,Default}/{Pictures,"My Documents",Uselessdir}
```

the glob here should do what you want:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf "%s\n" ./!(Public|Default)/@(Documents|My Documents|Pictures)
./other user/My Documents
./other user/Pictures
./Someuser/My Documents
./Someuser/Pictures
```

So, you should be able to just run

```
shopt -s extglob
find ./!(Public|Default)/@(Documents|My Documents|Pictures) ...
```

The glob will not expand to directories that don't exist, so you don't get errors from `find` if say `./Someuser/Pictures` doesn't exist.

Add `shopt -s nocaseglob` if you want a case-insensitive match.

Comment: Thanks! Is `extglob` case insensitive?

Comment: To answer my own comment, use `shopt -s nocaseglob` to ignore case when globbing

Answer (score 0):

Based on @StephaneChazelas comment using brace expansion, here's the solution I went with for `bash` that works with spaces in filenames and handles edge cases like only one user.

The string for brace expansion will be stored in a variable, so we need to use `eval` to actually expand it.

```
# escape spaces with backslash
directories=Documents,Pictures,My\ Documents

# get usernames to use with expansion
# and escape any spaces using sed
user_folders=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -iname Public -a -not -iname Default -type d -printf "%f," | \
sed 's| |\\ |g' )   

# remove trailing comma from last user's name
user_folders=${user_folders::-1}    

# only use brace expansion if there is more than one user; if there's only
# one value it won't expand and we'll be left with braces
[[ $user_folders = *,* ]] && user_folders="{$user_folders}"

find_string="find $user_folders/{$directories}"
eval "$find_string"
```

Comment: brace expansion not working with variables (and your need for eval here) is a limitation of bash. Other shells with brace expansion support like zsh or ksh93 don't have that limitation. Do you really have to use `bash` here?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes. it's part of a larger script with many bashisms...

Comment: Actually, that code above is `zsh` syntax. In `bash`, you'd need `eval "$find_string"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ... but (on Ubuntu) it works in bash too?

Comment: In `bash` `eval $find_string` invokes the split+glob operator so it would break on values that contain characters of `$IFS` or wildcard operators, see for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ok, I'll edit